# Windows 7 Installing FANN Python Bindings fails to find doublefann library

Tags: python-2.7, fann

I need help with  installing fann2 -- FANN Python Bindings
I have a windows 7 machine.
having installed Anaconda 64bit and  FANN I am trying to install the Python bindings using pip install fann2 .
It fails to find the Library doublefann
ld.exe: cannot find -ldoublefann
I get similar message using easy_install

C_INCLUDE_PATH

```
C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\FANN-2.2.0-Source\src\include;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\FANN-2.2.0-Source\src;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\FANN-2.2.0-Source\bin;
CPATH
C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\FANN-2.2.0-Source\src\include;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\FANN-2.2.0-Source\src;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\FANN-2.2.0-Source\bin;
Path
C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\app\myid_OO\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTex\miktex\bin\;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\swigwin-3.0.4;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\FANN-2.2.0-Source\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64;C:\Octave\Octave-3.8.2\bin;C:\Octave\Octave-3.8.2\;C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\FANN-2.2.0-Source\src\include
PYTHON_INCLUDE
C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\include
PYTHON_LIB
C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\libs
```

### Here is the pip.log

```
C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 02/02/15 22:52:18
Downloading/unpacking fann2
  Getting page  pypi.python.org/simple/fann2/
  URLs to search for versions for fann2:
  *  pypi.python.org/simple/fann2/
  Analyzing links from page  pypi.python.org/simple/fann2/
    Found link  pypi.python.org/packages/source/f/fann2/fann2-1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=b0db8db52ced14067c7ec143a269fb8b (from  pypi.python.org/simple/fann2/), version: 1.0.0
  Downloading from URL  pypi.python.org/packages/source/f/fann2/fann2-1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=b0db8db52ced14067c7ec143a269fb8b (from  pypi.python.org/simple/fann2/)
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_myid_OO\fann2\setup.py) egg_info for package fann2
    running swig
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\fann2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\fann2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\fann2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\fann2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\fann2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\fann2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\fann2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
```

Source in `c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_myid_OO\fann2` has version 1.0.0, which satisfies requirement fann2

```
Installing collected packages: fann2
  Running setup.py install for fann2
    Running command C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\myid~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_myid_OO\\fann2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-yaixqi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
    running swig
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2
    copying fann2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2
    copying fann2\libfann.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2
    running egg_info
    writing fann2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to fann2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to fann2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'fann2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'fann2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying fann2\fann2.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2
    copying fann2\fann2_wrap.cxx -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2
    copying fann2\fann_cpp_subclass.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2
    running build_ext
    building 'fann2._libfann' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2
    C:\Octave\Octave-3.8.2\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -DSWIG_COMPILE -I./include -I../include -Iinclude -IC:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\PC -c fann2/fann2_wrap.cxx -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2\fann2_wrap.o
    writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2\_libfann.def
    C:\Octave\Octave-3.8.2\bin\g++.exe -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2\fann2_wrap.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2\_libfann.def -LC:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 -ldoublefann -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2\_libfann.pyd
    c:/octave/octave-3.8.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldoublefann
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'C:\\Octave\\Octave-3.8.2\\bin\\g++.exe' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\myid~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_myid_OO\\fann2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-yaixqi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running swig

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2

copying fann2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2

copying fann2\libfann.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2

running egg_info

writing fann2.egg-info\PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to fann2.egg-info\top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to fann2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'fann2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

writing manifest file 'fann2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

copying fann2\fann2.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2

copying fann2\fann2_wrap.cxx -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2

copying fann2\fann_cpp_subclass.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2

running build_ext

building 'fann2._libfann' extension

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2

C:\Octave\Octave-3.8.2\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -DSWIG_COMPILE -I./include -I../include -Iinclude -IC:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\PC -c fann2/fann2_wrap.cxx -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2\fann2_wrap.o

writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2\_libfann.def

C:\Octave\Octave-3.8.2\bin\g++.exe -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2\fann2_wrap.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fann2\_libfann.def -LC:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 -ldoublefann -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fann2\_libfann.pyd

c:/octave/octave-3.8.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldoublefann

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'C:\\Octave\\Octave-3.8.2\\bin\\g++.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

---

Cleaning up...

```
Removing temporary dir c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_myid_OO...
Command C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\myid~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_myid_OO\\fann2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-yaixqi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_myid_OO\fann2
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Users\myid_OO\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\myid~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_myid_OO\\fann2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-yaixqi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\myid~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_myid_OO\fann2
```